# didRangeBeaconsInRegion() call multiple times after restarts Android app

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am developing Android app which scan near Beacons.
Very first time open Android app and scan near beacons and didRangeBeaconsInRegion() method call every 2 seconds.

But when I close app then again starts then didRangeBeaconsInRegion() method called 2 times in 2 seconds

3rd time didRangeBeaconsInRegion() method called 3 times in 2 seconds

and so on....

**Code snippet**

```
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, final Region region) {
    if (beacons != null) {
        Log.i("iBeacons", "beacons.size() : " + beacons.size());
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2018-12-29 21:39:40.328 26528-27120/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:40.328 26528-27120/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:40.328 26528-27120/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0

2018-12-29 21:39:42.259 26528-27124/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:42.260 26528-27124/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:42.260 26528-27124/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1

2018-12-29 21:39:44.229 26528-27132/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:44.229 26528-27132/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:44.229 26528-27132/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1

2018-12-29 21:39:46.241 26528-27136/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:46.241 26528-27136/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:46.241 26528-27136/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1

2018-12-29 21:39:48.251 26528-27138/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:48.251 26528-27138/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1
2018-12-29 21:39:48.251 26528-27138/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 1

2018-12-29 21:39:50.249 26528-27139/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:50.249 26528-27139/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:50.249 26528-27139/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0

2018-12-29 21:39:52.241 26528-27141/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:52.241 26528-27141/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
2018-12-29 21:39:52.241 26528-27141/com.test.demo I/iBeacons: beacons.size() : 0
```

---

***Update 2:***

Here the code for callbacks

```
mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
```

Above callback is called only one time form application once user allow all necessary permission for beacon scan operation

**Problem:** It is working fine in first time but issue with 2nd time, 3rd time, ... restarts.
I captured above logs when application was restarts 3rd time.

**Note:** It is also working fine when I clear the application form background.

Comment: Can you please show your code where you set up beacin ranging, including its context? It sounds  like you do this more than once causing multiple callbacks.

Comment: @davidgyoung: Please see my "Update 2" in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mBeaconManager.removeRangeNotifier(this);
```